# Adding insulation in a finished ceiling with no access

Tags: insulation, noise-reduction

I live in a condo that the builder decided not to put insulation between the different levels.  I don't own the condo above me.  With hardwood floors and no insulation it's very noisy.  My goal is creating a noise barrier, but insulation might do that as well.  The space is 8-10 inches between their floor and my ceiling.  Any suggestions on adding insulation to my ceiling?

Comment: How tall are your ceilings, some times a dropped ceiling with insulation is the best way as the wires don't transmit as much sound and insulation on the top of the panels kills much more noise.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a talk with the condo board is in order. Insulating the space between the floors would be beneficial for everyone, not just you. Cutting a few holes and blowing in cellulose would do a good job. Even better would be filling the space with mineral wool batts which are very good for soundproofing (and could be done as a DIY job) but that would require removing the ceiling drywall or plaster.

Answer (score 0):

Rip the ceiling, insulate, and put the new ceiling drywall on resilient channel. Or use an acoustic tile suspended ceiling as already suggested - if you have room to drop it 6" or so, you can insulate above the tiles without ripping the drywall off the ceiling.

As a "multiple dwelling unit" there probably are firecode issues (beyond single-family construction) you need to respect when working on the ceiling; check that before starting.